# How to graft from other repository?

Tags: mercurial

I have two repositories with tho different mercurual named branches, say V1 and V2. The branches are divergent since about one-two years. I'd like to graft some changesets from one repo into the other, without pulling the changes.

I don't want to pull the changes for multiple reasons.

- I don't want to conflict developers with history of multiple branches, because there will be enough local branches to care about.
- I want to have single branch central repos and developers could accidently push the second branch. The central branches would interact with SVN and should have only one branch per repo. I know I could use central hooks, to prevent such a push, but I don't want questions like, can't push, or how can I do that.
- The size of the repo would grow to multiple gigabytes (before pull about 700MB). As I understand, it's because of deficites of current mercurial storage format.

I know, the transplant extension can do the work. I tried it, but I can't force other developers to handle rejects instead of simply use a merge tool. Is there an other way?

In fact there are more then two repos with each a branch, but for the example simplicity two should be enough.

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer Yes, but it's like using transplant, you need to handle rejects instead of using a merge tool

Comment: maybe you can try to export a series of patches that have a common ancestor in both repo's? you could import those and then graft from there. But just handling the rejects might be easier

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do the work in an intermediate repo:

1. Pull in the changes
2. Do whatever grafting/rebasing/transplanting you need
3. Strip out the things you pulled in step 1. or if that doesn't work:

   1. Pull only the changes from the branch you want into the actual repo

You'd end up with a repository that includes your desired change sets, but not all the history from the unwanted branch.

Comment: It would work. But isn't it too much work for a simple graft/cherry-pic? Especially in my case I need to pull some gigabites. Shouldn't it go easear? I write a suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up to @DanMan

1. Pull needed branch into intermediate repo
2. Strip unwanted changesets in clone
3. `hg pull CLONE` in real target

Comment: I suggest you want to day "Graft" instead of "Strip" in the step 2

Comment: @iuzuz - no, strip... No nned for graft - I cloned only (single) needed branch

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I graft without graft/transplant/applying diff. Or does "Follow-up to.." mean, this steps should follow the steps of DanMan?

Comment: @iuzuz - you graft after step 3 - pulling stripped repo to your working repo. DanMan suggested pull the whole repo (I - only one branch) and graft-strip (I - strip-pull-graft)

Answer (score -1):

Write a tool, a hg-extension or extend the graft command so it can graft from a second repository, similar to the transplant extension.

Yes, the implementation is not so easy as adding the second-repo-functionality in the transplant command. The transplant extension simply uses a patch from an other repo instead of one from own repo. But I think also for graft there is no technical reason, not to do that.

If I understand right, grafting of a single file change is not more than calling the merge tool with the files:

- (base) the parent of the to-graft changeset
- (my changes) the target revision, on which to graft
- (theirs) the to-graft refision

So in order to graft a file change from an other repo, the whole file from other repo is needed before the to-graft changeset was applied (base) and after it was applied (theirs). Technically it should be no problem.

Additionally the implementation

- need to determine, which files are affected by the changeset to graft
- need to handle deletions correctly
- need to handle file renamings (not sure, how complicated it is)

All that should be possible, I see no real technical problems.